# ¿Cómo rellenar datos en un formulario con datos traídos de otro formulario y luego continuar con la carga de otros campos? En django

Tags: python, django, template

En django tengo dos tablas: Comprobantes y Orden_de_pago
En un template listo los datos de todos los comprobantes. Al seleccionar un comprobante quiero llevarme algunos datos a otro template y continuar con la carga de otros campos para generar una orden de pago y guardar en la tabla Orden_de_pago.
Alguien me podrá explicar con un ejemplo sencillo?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. En [es.so] no se dan orientaciones ni tutoriales: debes mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido.

Comment: Muestra tu codigo, tus tablas. Muestras lo que estas intentando, busca donde falla y intenta averiguar el porqué. Cuando sepas donde falla y no encuentres una solucion, ven a ésta comunidad y te ayudaremos.